# WebApi authorization filter with token in json payload

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've been looking into Authorization with AspNetWebApi and information is a little sparse on the subject.

I've got the following options:

1. Pass API token on query string
2. Pass API token as header
3. Pass API token using Basic Auth
4. Pass API token onto the request payload in json.

Which is generally the recommended method?

I'm also wondering for point 4), how would I go about inspecting the json payload in the OnAuthorization method on the AuthorizationFilterAttribute to check whether the API token is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by API token? Do you mean authentication cookie?

Comment: Just a GUID which can be passed in each request to authenticate the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a truly secure option for authorization, something like OAuth is the way to go. This [blog post](http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2011/10/11/oauth-2-0-in-web-api/) provides a pretty thorough sample using the now obsolete WCF Web API but a lot of the code is salvageable. Or at least, go with using HTTP basic authentication as shown in this [blog post](http://sixgun.co.uk/blog/2012/02/29/asp-net-web-api-basic-authentication/). As Aliostad notes, make sure you're using HTTPS if you go the Basic authentication route so the token stays secure.

If you decide you want to roll your own (which almost always will be much less secure than either option above) then below is a code sample of what you'll need for the AuthorizationHanlder if you go HTTP header route. Be aware there's a good chance the way the UserPrinicipal is handled in Web API classes may change so this code is only good for the first preview release. You would need to wire-in the AuthorizationHandler like this:

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler());
```

Code for header token:

```
public class AuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var requestAuthTokenList = GetRequestAuthTokens(request);
        if (ValidAuthorization(requestAuthTokenList))
        {
            //TODO: implement a Prinicipal generator that works for you
            var principalHelper = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .ServiceResolver
                    .GetService(typeof(IPrincipalHelper)) as IPrincipalHelper;

            request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.UserPrincipalKey] = 
                principalHelper.GetPrinicipal(request);

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        /*
        ** This will make the whole API protected by the API token.
        ** To only protect parts of the API then mark controllers/methods
        ** with the Authorize attribute and always return this:
        **
        ** return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        */
        return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(
            () => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Authorization failed")
                });
    }

    private static bool ValidAuthorization(IEnumerable<string> requestAuthTokens)
    {
        //TODO: get your API from config or however makes sense for you
        var apiAuthorizationToken = "good token";
        var authorized = requestAuthTokens.Contains(apiAuthorizationToken);

        return authorized;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetRequestAuthTokens(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> requestAuthTokens;
        if (!request.Headers.TryGetValues("SomeHeaderApiKey", out requestAuthTokens))
        {
            //Initialize list to contain a single not found token:
            requestAuthTokens = new[] {"No API token found"};
        }
        return requestAuthTokens;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely right, Aliostad! Its so ingrained I forgot to even mention it. Thanks!!

Comment: Is there any disadvantage between passing token in header or using Basic Auth? Is it a no-no to put API token in json with request? Also, how does the Principal Generator work?

Comment: I'd say separation of concerns would be why I wouldn't put the authorization token in the json body. If you put it in the body, there's a chance it may be part of what gets serialized into your models. If that what you want though, go for it.