# Mvc4 WepApi Empty Response when non 200

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

When an Action is called and throws a specific exception, I use an ExceptionFilterAttribute that translate the error into a different response as HttpStatusCode.BadRequest. This has been working locally, but we pushed it to a server and now when I get the BadRequest I do not get any information in the reponse. What am I missing?

```
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        MyException ex = actionExecutedContext.Exception as MyException;
        if (ex == null)
        {
            base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
            return;
        }

        IEnumerable<InfoItem> items = ex.Items.Select(i => new InfoItem
                                                                       {
                                                                           Property = i.PropertyName,
                                                                       Message = i.ToString()
                                                                   });

    actionExecutedContext.Result = new HttpResponseMessage<IEnumerable<InfoItem>>(items, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
```

Edit: When I hit the service locally the body is included.  It seems the problem is when hitting the service from a remote machine.

Comment: How is the items property being populated ?

Comment: They are set when the exception is thrown and items is not empty.

Comment: Sounds like the requests may not be making into the Web API pipeline. To verify they are, you could add a message handler to log incoming requests before they're routed over to the ApiController implementation. The code would be something like the authentication handler in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434389/webapi-authorization-filter-with-token-in-json-payload/10435013#10435013) and it also shows how to register it.

Comment: It works on all machines as long as the machine is hit locally.  The minute a remote machine hits the call the information is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = 
            IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always
```