# ASP.NET Web API: Non-descriptive 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api

As title says, I’ve got 500 Internal Server Error from GET request to an IQueryable action. The body of the error is empty. That error happens after my action returns result.

I use ASP.NET Web API RC.

How can I get stack trace of that error?

Comment: Berat, As I said, exception happens **after** my action returns result. I assume it happens when Web Api tries to serialize my collection. But I do not want to assume, I want to know exactly what's going on.

Comment: I have seen this as a known issue in one of the older versions. Which one do you use, beta or RC?

Comment: Aliostar, I think I already gave that detail in my original question. That’s RC.

Comment: I have the same issue when using the RC. In my case it's due to XML Serilization barfing (proven to my satisfaction by forcing JSON serilialization and everything working). I too would like to see the actual error get bubbled up when it occurs.

Comment: @stever-b I cleared xml formatter in Global.asax. But in my case xml formatter serialized entities correctly. I could see that by GET from the browser. Using getJSON from jquery results in JSON formatter been selected by WebAPI and, I guess, that is where something goes wrong.

Comment: @stever-b But again, I don't want to guess every time something goes wrong. All I want is to get detailed stacktrace from the server when something goes wrong.

Comment: I have same issue. I use custom MediaTypeFormatter and for me serialization is completed successfully (I put breakepoint and saw, that all entities correctrly serialized and written to response stream). Error is somewhere after serialization is done.

Comment: This is a bug in RC. There is no way of returning the error (exception message) in the response content when requesting a uri of your api remotely. The content length is always zero. I tried both IncludeErrorDetailPolicy and overriding the ExceptionFilterAttribute OnException but it did not work remotely regardless setting the customerrors in the web.config to "Off". The exception did come up when I used rdp on the remote server and did a request on the localhost using only IncludeErrorDetailPolicy setting. So unfortunately I believe that you cannot get the stack trace of the error yet.

Comment: Same error here. You wouldn't happen to have the Medium Trust turned on, would you?

Comment: @Sam Full trust. I was working with ISAPI which requires escalated privileges.

Comment: Is anything showing up in the event logs by any chance?

Comment: @oddy DId you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @sham Yes, I have switched to Java tech stack

Comment: I got frustrated by WebApi while I faced this error. The problem started when I updated Visual studio and also all the Nuget packages in my solution. 
I simply created a new ASP Core WebApi (without MVC) into my solution and I migrated by codes. I have been running fine ever after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Post RC, this issue was fixed and you will be getting error details also apart from the 500 Internal Server Error. (This issue is fixed for Web Host scenarios only though).

You could do the following to get the details of the actual exception which might be occurring during a formatter's WriteToStream method.

```
ObjectContent<IEnumerable<Product>> responseContent = new ObjectContent<IEnumerable<Product>>(db.Products.Include(p => p.ProductSubcategory).AsEnumerable(), new XmlMediaTypeFormatter()); // change the formatters accordingly

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            // This line would cause the formatter's WriteToStream method to be invoked.
            // Any exceptions during WriteToStream would be thrown as part of this call
            responseContent.CopyToAsync(ms).Wait();
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding this to my action and then setting a break point was the only way I could see the exception. Cheers!

Comment: So it's not fixed for selfhost?

Comment: Post RC isn't released yet right? Unless you build from sources?

Answer (score 60):

You can try adding:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = 
    IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

to your `Application_Start()` in the Global.asax.  This solution works for many of the common errors.

If, however, you aren't getting satisfactory information  you should consider writing an l **Exception Filter** and registering it globally.

[This article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling) should get you started.  The core of what you need is to write & register something like:

```
public class NotImplExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute {
  public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) {
     if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException) {
       context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @EBarr I already tried that before I posted my question. I saw your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487943/mvc4-wepapi-empty-response-when-non-200 It does not work somehow. My error 500 still has an empty body. I used “Network” tab in Chrome to see answers from the server.

Comment: @Oddy - When the above fails, I haven't found a great way to debug.  When the error is happening after your action returns I see a few avenues -  1) the above, 2) your return is an IEnumerable that executes an erroring query.  Try a `.ToList()` to check the query,  3) Disable or debug the 2nd half of any message handlers ( the `ContinueWith()` section) or 3) the output formatting is breaking (json, or xml) so use fiddler/whatever to ask for an alternate format.

Comment: @SteverB - not sure why someone downvoted you.  This answer works in many scenarios.

Comment: @EBarr 1. Above does not work. If it works for you in RC, then it must be me who did something above described. I’ll double check it in a few hours. 2. I return IQueryable, you might already saw that detail in my question. 3. Before I turned off xml formatter xml was correct. I found the issue after all, when I connected JSON.NET as my formatter instead of the default DataContract serializer. But as I said earlier, I’m not interested in that. I need details for the server error whenever they occur.

Comment: @EBarr I downwoted that answer. It works for some people on SO. But I haven't seen version of the framework. MVC 4 RC differs from Beta. Web API was changed. When it will work for me, I'll upwote it and mark as an answer. Otherwise, if that won't work, this answer will confuse those who have exactly the same issue.

Comment: The description in your question is fairly generic and covers many possible scenarios.  SO users are a pretty smart bunch -- i think it gives them an avenue to explore & won't confuse them.

Comment: I have this exact same issue; I've tried custom Exception filter, global config, etc.

It is happening at the end of the pipeline after all events. Just a server 500 nothing else. Even moved the site to IIS 7.5 and turned on IIS Tracing - all that did was confirm the 500, nothing else, no stack, nothing to let me know the failure.

100% repro in small solution too.

Comment: @EBarr my description of the problem is short and to the point. No one asked to add more details to it, as you can see. And I still cannot get details for the server error 500 returned by the server using aforementioned approach.

Comment: @diaho Do you use RC version?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue. I found [Kiran Challa's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11004784/204065) helpful in getting the actual exception being thrown outside of my action.

To solve my issue, [setting the ProxyCreationEnabled property of my context to false](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/1c37447a-e303-4947-a3ee-d2e6592aac0a) got me a step further.

In my scenario, my next exception was due to a circular reference in my models. After cleaning that up, the phantom 500 response was gone. Good luck if you haven't solved this yet!

Answer (score 4):

A deceivingly simple routing weakness caused this problem in my case: There was another HttpPost with the same signature (not name) in my Api Controller. The default routing did not resolve the name differences, and the ServiceError 500 was the response it gave before either of the Api functions were reached. Solution: change the default routing or your signatures and try again.

Here is my RouteConfig.cs that works quite well for standard WebApi2 usage:

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Default is required in any case.
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems mad, there was me thinking it should just pick up up out of the box. I'm not sure I ever would have found this. This must be a real ache for anyone with lots of methods that pass a single JSON object etc.

Comment: Assume it is perhaps a feature not a bug ... it drove us nuts too :-) ... or will be fixed in WebApi3.

Answer (score 3):

This may be related to circular reference.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#handling_circular_object_references

Try adding the following code to Application_Start method in the Global.asax file:

```
 var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
 json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue in RC when I was not specifying query parameters in the right order.  For example, if you specify `$skip=0`, it will get 500, but if you specify `$orderby=xxx&skip=0` no error.

Answer (score 2):

This Scenario was caused for the following reasons

1. The problem occurred due to misformed Web.config. ( Multiple configSections)
2. Instead of creating  **roslyn** folder inside **bin** folder, I had it created at the root. (Deployment location.)

The best way to diagnose this was, to put a simple HTML page at the application location and try to browse it. 500 Error description will be displayed on this html page.

And also don't forget to add

> `<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>`

to Web.config

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the Global.asax to catch all error. Here is a code snip you can use

```
public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
  MvcApplication mvcApplication = sender as MvcApplication;
  HttpRequest request = null;
  if (mvcApplication != null) request = mvcApplication.Request;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the source of it was slightly different:
I set the `CORS` policy incorrectly and that gives me `500 Internal server error`, but since `CORS` was not working, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header was not presented in response and browser can't read the actual response

I solved it with ChromeDevTools option `Copy as cURL` which allows me see the response and understand the source of error

Answer (score 0):

Fredrik Normén wrote a great blog post called [ASP.NET Web API Exception Handling](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/06/11/asp-net-web-api-exception-handling.aspx) about that topic. His solution uses custom exception classes and an exception filter attribute that can be applied to all `ApiController` action methods.