# Web API error on localhost

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am starting developing an Web API using ASP.NET Core MVC. I have been following this Microsoft tutorial: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api`

So far, I have created the code for the following operations:

- GET /api/todo
- GET /api/todo/{id}

Code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TodoController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITodoRepository _todoRepository;

    public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoRepository)
    {
        _todoRepository = todoRepository;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetAll()
    {
        return _todoRepository.GetAll();
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name ="GetTodo")]
    public IActionResult GetById(long id)
    {
        var item = _todoRepository.Find(id);

        if(item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }
}
```

However, when I run the Application I am getting the following 500 error:

[image]

I understand what the error means, by not why it's happening. Did I miss something?

The interesting part is that I can access the API that was autogenerated when creating the application. But not the new one I added manually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944938/asp-net-web-api-non-descriptive-500-internal-server-error

Comment: Can you add your WebApiConfig.cs to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Change Settings in your Properties -> launchSettings.json File.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49885",
      "sslPort": 44337
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/todo",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "TodoApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/todo",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

because by default the "lauchUrl" is set to "api/values" this is the reason why you were getting that error. 
Also add this in your Todo Controller, refer the documentation for why this should be added.

```
namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/todo")]
    [ApiController]
```

I suggest you to  follow the guidelines for creating the app till  the last and run it after completion to avoid error.