# Correct usage of AuthorizationFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Say I have a xml like the following which gets posted to an api controller:

```
<request>
<header><api_key>Somekey</api_key></header>
</request>
```

If I want to validate the api key in a custom AuthorizationFilterAttribute like so:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    // Deserialize the posted message and validate the api key.
}
```

How can I do that without having to manually deserialize it?

Comment: I would recommend putting the API key in an HTTP Header or in the query string, as opposed to the body with the request data.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to do something like what I [answered to a similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434389/webapi-authorization-filter-with-token-in-json-payload/10435013#10435013) Mind all the caveats in the answer and the comments ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean you don't wnat to "manually deserialize it"? Are you referring to the automatic modelbinding that the controllers support? If so, you won't be able to take advantage of those at that point in the pipeline.

To echo peco's comment, you shouldn't be putting an api key in the body but rather in the header or querystring.